# Memory Leak in OpenCV Set Size

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I am finding a memory leak in this simple OpenCV code:

```
VideoCapture* capture = new VideoCapture(0);
Mat frame;
while (true) {
    capture->set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1600 );
    capture->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1200 );
    capture->read(frame);
}
```

This is the whole code.  Every time through the while loop, several MB are leaked.  I have tried frame.release() just after the read, but it doesn't help.  Removing the set-size lines fixes the problem, but in my real code I want to vary the size, so that isn't a solution.  It is getting the image at the correct size.

Am I doing something stupid?

By the way, I am using a Logitech B910 webcam.

Thanks!

Comment: since the frame you read there is kind of static / points to driver memory, could you add your os / opencv version ? it's probably a problem with a very specific capture implementation

Comment: I am using the apt-get version from Ubuntu 12.04, which is OpenCV 2.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to change the readout size on every frame?

Once it is set the camera will produce the same size until you reset it

Comment: Right.  This code is just to demonstrate the bug.  In my application I hope to get small images most of the time, then switch to high-quality images at other times.